# Testing Android app: Exception during suite construction

Tags: android, eclipse, junit, robotium

I have a simple application that I'm trying to test.  It has two activities and two buttons (each button goes to the other activity - MainActivity and MainActivity2), and I'm trying to make some simple Robotium tests of it.  I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception during suite construction at
>   android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests.testSuiteConstructionFailed(TestSuiteBuilder.java:238)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191) at
>   android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176) at
>   android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1840)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at
>   android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.instantiateTest(TestMethod.java:87)
>   at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.createTest(TestMethod.java:73)
>   at
>   android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTest(TestSuiteBuilder.java:262)
>   at
>   android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.build(TestSuiteBuilder.java:184)
>   at
>   android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:379)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5142)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:156) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1418)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:338) at
>   android.view.View.(View.java:3490) at
>   android.view.View.(View.java:3547) at
>   android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:674) at
>   android.widget.Button.(Button.java:107) at
>   android.widget.CompoundButton.(CompoundButton.java:68) at
>   android.widget.CheckBox.(CheckBox.java:68) at
>   android.widget.CheckBox.(CheckBox.java:64) at
>   android.widget.CheckBox.(CheckBox.java:60) at
>   com.example.twoactivities.test.RobotiumTest1.(RobotiumTest1.java:19)
>   ... 18 more

I've tried everything I can find, and none of those solutions work for me.  (No parameters in constructor, checking build path to ensure JARs are in the right place, ensuring that my application under test is "debuggable", etc.)

My code is here:

```
package com.example.twoactivities.test;

import com.example.twoactivities.*;
import com.robotium.solo.Solo;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.app.Activity;    

public class RobotiumTest1 extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

        private Solo solo;

        public RobotiumTest1() {
            super(MainActivity.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            //setUp() is run before a test case is started. 
            //This is where the solo object is created.
            solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
        }

//      @Override
//      public void tearDown() throws Exception {
//          //tearDown() is run after a test case has finished. 
//          //finishOpenedActivities() will finish all the activities that have been opened during the test execution.
//          solo.finishOpenedActivities();
//      }


        public void testClickButton() throws Exception{

            solo.assertCurrentActivity("Expected to be on MainActivity activity", "MainActivity.class");
            solo.clickOnButton("Go to page 2");
            solo.assertCurrentActivity("Not on Activity 2", MainActivity2.class);
            solo.clickOnButton("Go to page 1");
            solo.assertCurrentActivity("Not on Activity 1", MainActivity.class);

        }       

    }
```

Any ideas how I can get this test to run?

Thanks,
Stephanie

EDIT:

MainActivity

```
package com.example.twoactivities;

import com.example.twoactivities.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        final TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxTextView);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void activity2(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,com.example.twoactivities.MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onCheckBoxClicked(View view){
        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
            text2.setText("Checked");
        }
        else {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxTextView)).setText("Unchecked");
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity2

```
package com.example.twoactivities;

import com.example.twoactivities.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

    public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
           }

           public void activity1(View view){
              Intent intent = new Intent(this,com.example.twoactivities.MainActivity.class);
              startActivity(intent);
           }

}
```

I actually haven't changed anything (I don't think) since it last ran successfully.

**Sept 12 edits:**
"solo" object was being initialized after I was trying to use it.

```
package com.example.twoactivities.test;

import com.example.twoactivities.*;
import com.example.twoactivities.R;
import com.robotium.solo.Solo;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class RobotiumTest1 extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

        public Solo solo;
        private TextView checkBoxText; 
        public CheckBox checkBox1 ;

        public RobotiumTest1() {
            super(MainActivity.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            //setUp() is run before a test case is started. 
            //This is where the solo object is created.
            solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
            checkBoxText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.checkBoxTextView);
            checkBox1 = (CheckBox) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        }

        public void testClickButton() throws Exception{

            solo.assertCurrentActivity("Expected to be on MainActivity activity", "MainActivity");
            solo.clickOnButton("Go to page 2");
            solo.assertCurrentActivity("Not on Activity 2", MainActivity2.class);
            solo.clickOnButton("Go to page 1");
            solo.assertCurrentActivity("Not on Activity 1", MainActivity.class);

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clue is in the log you posted.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:338) 
at android.view.View.(View.java:3490) 
at android.view.View.(View.java:3547) 
at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:674) 
at android.widget.Button.(Button.java:107) 
at android.widget.CompoundButton.(CompoundButton.java:68) 
at android.widget.CheckBox.(CheckBox.java:68) 
at android.widget.CheckBox.(CheckBox.java:64) 
at android.widget.CheckBox.(CheckBox.java:60) at com.example.twoactivities.test.RobotiumTest1.(RobotiumTest1.java:19) ... 18 more
```

You have a `NullPointerException` causing you the issues, this `NullPointerException` is in your applications code not the code posted here however (Note if you add it, I will look into it here for you)

*EDIT*
The code below is the issue:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
            final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            final TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxTextView);
```

The problem is you are trying to find views that do not actually exist until onCreate() is called so these will be null. move the initialisation of these to onCreate() and you should be ok.

*Next edit to answer your question in comments.*

Ok so now we are away from Robotium and in to core Java, the issue you have now is scope, the thing is where you declare a variable and it is accesible is different to where you instantiate it. You can declare the variables existance in the same scope as you are currently but instantiate it in `onCreate()`.

```
package com.example.twoactivities;

import com.example.twoactivities.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        final CheckBox checkBox;
        final TextView text2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxTextView);
    }

    public void activity2(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,com.example.twoactivities.MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onCheckBoxClicked(View view){
        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
            text2.setText("Checked");
        }
        else {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxTextView)).setText("Unchecked");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm...if I do that, then I can't use them in onCheckBoxClicked.  They are out of scope.

Comment: Fixed the main program to instantiate in the onCreate - main program works perfectly now.  JUnit test fails with the above NullPointerException.  (I feel like we're going in circles here.  :) )

Comment: Paul, a co-worker was able to debug for me.  Check out the solution. Thanks so much for your all your help!